# Design pattern fu for converting between subclasses

Tags: java, design-patterns

We are writing a hierarchy of classes that implement various ways to represent languages. There is a base `LanguageCode` class with several subclasses, including `ISO1LanguageCode` for [ISO 639-1 codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) (example: 'en'), `ISO2LanguageCode` for [ISO 639-2 codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-2_codes) (example: 'eng'), and `HumanReadableLanguageCode` (example: 'English'). At any time, we need to be able to convert between any two of the subclasses. Is there some design pattern magic we could use here to help?

#### Note:

Our first idea was to standardize the base class and make each subclass write a conversion routine between itself and the standard on the base class. That way, to convert between `ISO2LanguageCode` and `HumanReadableLanguageCode`, use `LanguageCode` as a bridge.

Comment: What's the use case? Are you trying to manage Text throughout an application? Switch between languages as requested?

Answer (score 2):

There is only one set of languages. Each language has an -1 code, a useless -2 code, and a -3 code. And a human-readable name. So make one enum with accessors to return the different codes, and multiple lookup static methods.